# Why are these javascript event listeners working, but with the wrong values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, listener

For some reason, the average_on variable is toggling incorrectly on the resize event only.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeEmptyCanvas, true);

$("#update_graph").click(function(){
    var cpu_on = document.getElementById('cpu_trending').checked ? "yes" : "no";
    var ram_on = document.getElementById('ram_trending').checked ? "yes" : "no";$
    var net_up_on = document.getElementById('net_up_trending').checked ? "yes" : "no";
    var net_down_on = document.getElementById('net_down_trending').checked ? "yes" : "no";
    var average_on = document.getElementById('average_trending').checked ? true : false;
    var time_num = $('#select_time_num').val();
    var time_unit = $('#select_time_unit').val();
    var time_period = time_num + time_unit;

    if (cpu_on=='yes'){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('trending_graph_canvas');
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth-80;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight/2-20;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        GetTrendCPU(time_period, function(data, server_time){

            window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeEmptyCanvas, false);
            window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeEmptyCanvas, true);

            resizeCanvas(canvas, data, server_time, time_period, average_on);

            window.addEventListener('resize', function(){

                resizeCanvas(canvas, data, server_time, time_period, average_on);
                }, true);
        });
    }
});

function GetTrendCPU(time_period, CallBack){
    $.post("plugins/analytics/analytics_responder.php",
        {get_time: true},
        function(data){
            var now_time = data;
            $.post("plugins/analytics/analytics_responder.php",
                {cpu_use_trending: true, time_period: time_period},
                function(data){
                    if (data=='ERROR'){
                        CallBack('ERROR');
                    }else{
                        var cpu_trends = JSON.parse(data);
                        CallBack(cpu_trends, now_time);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
}

function resizeCanvas(canvas, data, now, time_period, average) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth-80;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight/2-20;
    DrawTrending(ctx, canvas.width, canvas.height, data, now, time_period, average);
}
```

The error is that the average_on variable is 100% correct when the resize canvas runs, but 80% not correct when it runs in the event listener. The problem is this, here is what I need:

- once the page loads the blank canvas should resize to certain dimensions defined in resizeEmptyCanvas and should do that dynamically.
- once the user presses to update the graph, all the settings are gathered, then the associated data is gathered, then the graph is updated as well as the listener (with the new data/settings).

I think the problem has something to do with me not wanting to have to grab the same data twice (can be a lot) but the asynchronous behavior of Ajax may require it. It's too much data to grab twice.

I suspect if I could just return the sql results from the function GetTrendCPU it would be workable, but that doesn't appear possible with post. I have tried 100s of variations of the code at this point... nothing appears able to achieve the intent.

Comment: It looks like your `resizeCanvas` call in your event listener is out of scope for the variables you want to pass to it. When the `addEventListener` function calls that callback, it does not know what those parameters mean.

Comment: I think I agree.. complicated issues. I tried defining the time_period and  average_on variables inside the event, but then I think maybe they getElementByID reference became out of scope. I don't know what else to do... I can't return from GetTrendCPU since post is used, which means I have to put the data updates inside the callback, which makes the variables go out of scope. I've tried this 100 different ways, seems to be a limitation of javascript... doesn't seem to handle dynamic events too well... or am I missing something... added resize canvas function too.

Comment: Honestly... the above code behaves very strangely, all the strangeness is centered around the average_on function and how that reacts with the event... it's the event just sees a wrong value, it's very strange behavior from that value. this variable controls where the plots are averaged into one function or drawn separately. True means it averages. Everything works 100% until I start resizing the page, in which case average_on=false changes to true and the graph turns into an average. The inverse has happened but is much rarely... behavior seems to change the longer I play with it.

Comment: "GetTrendCPU(canvas, time_period, average_on, function(cpu_trends, server_time, canvas, time_period, average_on){"... thought this might fix it, but no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

This works flawlessly, but I do not fully understand why so I can't explain it all. I split the draw function off from the resize function for readability primarily. I defined the dates (a) with careful attention to name variables of a different scope differently, and (b) with a BIG assumption that the events would effectively and automatically overwrite the old one (an invalid assumption with the old code... but surprise! It works now!). Does anyone know why? I have one big problem now... every time I press update_graph it bogs down the server to 50-100% CPU use... more and more with each press, erg.

```
//Initialize Graph
var canvas_init = document.getElementById('trending_graph_canvas');
var ctx_init = canvas_init.getContext('2d');
canvas_init.width = window.innerWidth-80;
canvas_init.height = window.innerHeight/2-20;
var time_num_init = $('#select_time_num').val();
var time_unit_init = $('#select_time_unit').val();
var time_period_init = time_num_init + time_unit_init;
var show_points_init = document.getElementById('show_points').checked ? true : false;
var average_on_init = document.getElementById('average_trending').checked ? true : false;

GetTrendCPU(time_period_init, function(data, server_time){
    resizeCanvas(canvas_init);
    DrawTrending(ctx_init, canvas_init.width, canvas_init.height, data, server_time, time_period_init, average_on_init, show_points_init);
});

GetTrendCPU(time_period_init, function(data, server_time){
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
        resizeCanvas(canvas_init);
        DrawTrending(ctx_init, canvas_init.width, canvas_init.height, data, server_time, time_period_init, average_on_init, show_points_init);
    }, true);
});
//window.addEventListener('resize', resizeEmptyCanvas, true);


$("#update_graph").click(function(){
    var cpu_on = document.getElementById('cpu_trending').checked ? "yes" : "no";
    var ram_on = document.getElementById('ram_trending').checked ? "yes" : "no";$
    var net_up_on = document.getElementById('net_up_trending').checked ? "yes" : "no";
    var net_down_on = document.getElementById('net_down_trending').checked ? "yes" : "no";
    var show_points = document.getElementById('show_points').checked ? true : false;
    var average_on = document.getElementById('average_trending').checked ? true : false;
    var time_num = $('#select_time_num').val();
    var time_unit = $('#select_time_unit').val();
    var time_period = time_num + time_unit;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('trending_graph_canvas');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth-80;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight/2-20;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (cpu_on=='yes'){


        GetTrendCPU(time_period, function(data, server_time){
            resizeCanvas(canvas);
            DrawTrending(ctx, canvas.width, canvas.height, data, server_time, time_period, average_on, show_points);
        });

        GetTrendCPU(time_period, function(data, server_time){
            window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
                resizeCanvas(canvas);
                DrawTrending(ctx, canvas.width, canvas.height, data, server_time, time_period, average_on, show_points);
            }, true);
        });

    }
    if (ram_on=='yes'){


    }
});
```

Comment: Note that things act up when I try to combine the two GetTrendCPU functions inside the cpu_on if. Very strange... but I'm not touching it anymore. Wish I didn't have to call it twice, talking about up to 90 days worth a logs...